# Converting GPS to Cartesian

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-coordinates

I'm trying to convert GPS coordinates into Cartesian so I can use them in a Unity application.  I'm using the below function to do so, but it seems the values I'm using are not quite placed at the right location.  My guess is that there's an issue due to the shape of the Earth.  I've also included a picture of my data, which should resemble a flat loop, but instead is at an incline. [Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFYL4.jpg)

```
Vector3 WGS84ToCartesian(float lat, float lon, float h){
float earthRadius = 6378137.0f;

float cosLat = Mathf.Cos(lat * Mathf.PI / 180.0f);
float sinLat = Mathf.Sin(lat * Mathf.PI / 180.0f);
float cosLon = Mathf.Cos(lon * Mathf.PI / 180.0f);
float sinLon = Mathf.Sin(lon * Mathf.PI / 180.0f);

float f = 1.0f / 298.257224f;
float C = 1.0f / Mathf.Sqrt(cosLat * cosLat + (1 - f) * (1 - f) * sinLat * sinLat);
float S = (1.0f - f) * (1.0f - f) * C;

float x = (earthRadius * C + h) * cosLat * cosLon;
float y = (earthRadius * C + h) * cosLat * sinLon;
float z = (earthRadius * S + h) * sinLat;

return new Vector3(x, y, z);
```

}

Comment: What's the input data? Can you post at least three points, one at the beginning, one at about 1/3rd of the way, and one at 2/3rds?

Comment: From what I deduced by your explanation, you want the local tangent plane (local ground) to be horizontal in your result. You would have to rotate your coordinates for that, because the 3D conversion has the Equator plane as XY plane, not a local tangent plane.

Comment: The Lat/Lon/Height to ECEF (xyz) formulae can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#From_geodetic_to_ECEF_coordinates). Then you would need to apply the rotation matrix to convert from [ECEF to ENU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#From_ECEF_to_ENU) coordinates from a chosen reference point.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the Earth's shape is a geoid. The ellipsoid is still an approximation of its shape that can diverge by as much as 100 meters from sea level. To get actual 3D coordinates, you need to set the GPS to output ellipsoidal heights (heights without geoid correction). If your heights were elevations relative to sea level, you need to add the geoid height to your elevations. Although if you are working in a relatively small area, this won't make any practical difference for relative distances and shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution assumes that the earth is a sphere. It's not. According to Wikipedia, the polar diameter is about 3,950, while the equatorial diameter is more like 3,963 mi, about a 13 mile difference, about $0.3\%$. That's probably enough to mess up your computations.

(It's certainly enough to mess up a pendulum clock --- apparently a friend of Newton's moved from Paris to Cayenne, and found that his nicely calibrated clock now ran slower than it should, from which Newton determined that the earth must not be round, and even came up with a good estimate of its eccentricity. The details (which I've surely muddled up a bit) are in Spivak's "Physics for Mathematicians", should you be interested.

Comment: That's interesting!  I thought the irregularity of the Earth was slight enough that it wouldn't be noticeable in smaller contexts like these.  So when it comes to accounting for this, do I just shift everything according to that .3% distance?

Comment: No. Instead, do a Google search on "wgs84 to cartesian" and read the articles that are written by people who do GIS for a living. This is a pretty well-established conversion (that's why WGS84 is a **standard**).

Comment: I've been looking and have had no success in finding a solution which does not assume the Earth is a sphere.  How would you even account for the Earth's non-constant radius?